# Xubuntu No WUBILDR error

Tags: installation, windows-7, wubi, xubuntu

I downloaded Xubuntu trough the wubi installer on Windows 7 and it worked just fine, But when i choose Xubuntu at the boot menu i get the NO WUBILDR error and then it just continues and I log on just fine... So far it hasn't effected Xubuntu much and i am able to continue using it, But seeing the error everytime is a bit annoying, how do i fix it? I've tried tons of thing's ive tried replacing the wubildr files with the one's in the winboot folder, and uninstalling/reinstalling, but nothing works. I've checked tons of other websites and forums and the likes and havent found anything that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi uses Grub4Dos (wubildr.mbr). Part of it's job is to find it's second stage (wubildr). It looks on all partitions and outputs a diagnostic if it can't find it.

Something like this would mean that the first partition is FAT32 and there is no /wubildr:

`Try (hd0,0): FAT32: No wubildr`

This isn't an error. You can copy the wubildr to the root of the first partition to stop it showing, or just ignore it (my recommendation).

There is another message that shows on all Wubi installs:

`Error: 'prefix' not set`

There's nothing you can do to get rid of this. (No known workarounds). It's registered as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/927157). My advice, is to ignore it, or install a normal dual boot if it bothers you that much.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just check out this forum. it may help you the most. I am sick of writing long solutions. osrry, its early in the morning and I haven't slept yet. 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198

One similar problem stating same is here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878427